# PHP: How do I display the contents of a textfile on my page?

Tags: php, echo

I have a .txt file on my web server (locally) and wish to display the contents within a page (stored on the same server) via PHP echo.

The .txt file contains a number that is updated by another script on another page, but for this page I just want to pull the number/txt file contents from the file and echo it (to save the page having to do the calculation involved in getting the number again).

How can I do this?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    <?php
    $myFile = "http://renownestates.com/cache/feedSubscribers.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $theData = fread($fh, 1);
    fclose($fh);
    echo $theData;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 63):

Here, try this (assuming it's a small file!):

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents( "filename.php" ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
?>
```

Documentation is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: Does it matter if this code snippet is contained within the sidebar of a WordPress theme? ..ive replaced 'filename.php. with 'www.domain.com/myfile.txt' and its not working :(

Comment: Aah, ive got it working now! took out the URL and just went ../fileLocation. Thank you!!!! :D

Answer (score 13):

For just reading file and outputting it the best one would be [`readfile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: This would return bytes of the file, not the content

Answer (score 8):

If you aren't looking to do anything to the stuff in the file, just display it, you can actually just `include()` it.  `include` works for any file type, but of course it runs any php code it finds inside.

Answer (score 8):

I had to use nl2br to display the carriage returns correctly and it worked for me:

```
<?php
echo nl2br(file_get_contents( "filename.php" )); // get the contents, and echo it out.
?>
```

Comment: above can be used for .txt files too.

Answer (score 5):

I have to display files of computer code. If special characters are inside the file like less than or greater than, a simple "include" will not display them. Try:

```
$file = 'code.ino';
$orig = file_get_contents($file);
$a = htmlentities($orig);

echo '<code>';
echo '<pre>';

echo $a;

echo '</pre>';
echo '</code>';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

**Try this to open a file in php**

Refer this: (http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_file_fopen)

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to show the file itself:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.txt"');
readfile(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)